# Simulating Chrome extensions' background and content scripts with Internet Explorer BHO / plug-in

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, bho

I'm looking to write a JS library\toolkit like [Kango](http://kangoextensions.com/). Kango allows one to write JS code which executes in all major browsers. Chrome and Firefox have a nice system which allows for long-running processes to run in a background page, while also running scripts on page load (content scripts) while allowing the two to communicate via messaging.

Unfortunately, IE doesn't really have a straightforward system like this. Instead, it looks like the best solution is to use a [Browser Helper Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load the background/content scripts somehow.

I'm not exactly sure how to get started.

Is it possible for the BHO to run an invisible IE instance which runs the background script so that the background script is executed in a separate environment? If so, how would content scripts and said background page communicate?

How would I make my JS libraries available to both types of scripts? How would a response from a background script (an XMLHTTPRequest object) find its way to a content script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use C# in BHOs, but C++ (unless your goal is to slow down IE as much as possible). If you agree, change the C# tag to C++ and I will consider writing an answer.

Comment: Your input would be very much appreciated

Comment: Take a look at these two examples to understand how BHOs work, to get started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C (tutorial + code) and http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/bho.html (code only). Let me know if you're able to understand it.

Comment: I've actually googled both of those pages before. I sort of understand it, but I imagine simulating background.html in IE via BHO's will require all sorts of things, such as exposing c++ methods to javascript, running said background invisibly, etc. I was hoping for a bird's-eye view of how to engineer something like that; not just how to build a BHO itself which I can (painstakingly) do alright by myself.

Comment: Trigger.io recently open sourced its browser extension libraries. https://github.com/trigger-corp/browser-extensions